# Python Idiom for applying sequential steps to an iterable

Tags: python, idioms

When doing data processing tasks I often find myself applying a series of compositions, vectorized functions, etc. to some input iterable of data to generate a final result. Ideally I would like something that will work for both lists and generators (in addition to any other iterable). I can think of a number of approaches to structuring code to accomplish this, but every way I can think of has one or more ways where it feels unclean/unidiomatic to me. I have outlined below the different methods I can think of to do this, but my question is—**is there a recommended, idiomatic way to do this?**

Methods I can think of, illustrated with a simple example that is generally representative of:

## Write it as one large expression

```
result = [sum(group) 
          for key, group in itertools.groupby(
              filter(lambda x: x <= 2, [x **2 for x in input]),
               keyfunc=lambda x: x % 3)]
```

This is often quite difficult to read for any non-trivial sequence of steps. When reading through the code one also encounters each step in reverse order.

## Save each step into a different variable name

```
squared = [x**2 for x in input]
filtered = filter(lambda x: x < 2, squared)
grouped = itertools.groupby(filtered, keyfunc=lambda x: x % 3)
result = [sum(group) for key, group in grouped]
```

This introduces a number of local variables that can often be hard to name descriptively; additionally, if the result of some or all of the intermediate steps is especially large keeping them around could be very wasteful of memory. If one wants to add a step to this process, care must be taken that all variable names get updated correctly—for example, if we wished to divide every number by two we would add the line `halved = [x / 2.0 for x in filtered]`, but would also have to remember to change `filtered` to `halved` in the following line.

## Store each step into the same variable name

```
tmp = [x**2 for x in input]
tmp = filter(lambda x: x < 2, tmp)
tmp = itertools.groupby(tmp, keyfunc=lambda x: x % 3)
result = [sum(group) for key, group in tmp]
```

I guess this seems to me as the least-bad of these options, but storing things in a generically named placeholder variable feels un-pythonic to me and makes me suspect that there is some better way out there.

Comment: This is largely a matter of opinion and preferred style. There are other styles, e.g. [`fluent interface`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) or [`method chaining`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) that would allow a more natural cascading of calls.

Answer (score 1):

Code Review often is a better place for style questions. SO is more for problem solving.  But CR can be picky about the completeness of the example.

But I can a few observations:

- if you wrap this calculation in a function, naming isn't such a big deal.  The names don't have to be globally meaningful.
- a number of your expressions are generators.  Itertools tends to produce generators or gen. expressions.  So memory use shouldn't be much of an issue.

---

```
def better_name(input):
   squared = (x**2 for x in input)   # gen expression
   filtered = filter(lambda x: x < 2, squared)
   grouped = itertools.groupby(filtered, lambda x: x % 3)
   result = (sum(group) for key, group in grouped)
   return result

list(better_name(input))
```

Using `def` functions instead of lambdas can also make the code clearer.  There's a trade off.  Your lambdas are simple enough that I'd probably keep them.

Your 2nd option is much more readable than the 1st.  The order of the expressions guides my reading and mental evaluation.  In the 1st it's hard to identify the inner-most or first evaluation.  And `groupby` is a complex operation, so any help in compartmentalizing the action is welcome.

---

Following the `filter` docs, these are equivalent:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x < 2, squared)
filtered = (x for x in squared if x<2)
```

I was missing the `return`.  The function could return a generator as I show, or an evaluated list.

`groupby` `keyfunc` is not a keyword argument, but rather positional one.

`groupby` is complex function.  It returns a generator that produces tuples, an element of which is a generator itself.  Returning this makes it more obvious.

```
((key, list(group)) for key, group in grouped)
```

So a code style that clarifies its use is desirable.